# Surface plot with LaTeX code in label

Tags: matlab, plot, latex, matlab-figure

I would like to use the Letter μ (LaTeX: `\mu`) in my surface plot. Unfortunately when I use the LaTeX symbol `\mu` in the `zlabel('Power [\muW]');` command it results in:

'Power [ μ W]' instead of 'Power [μW]'

How can I avoid these spaces around μ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem, which could be due to you using an older version of Matlab. In the past it was neccesary to set the **latex interpreter** fist, before using Latex syntax. So the following should work:

```
zlabel('Power [$$\mu$$W]','interpreter','latex');
```

Nowadays it seems to recognize automatically at least greek letters.